# JAVA help, I cant seem to find the error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner at java, i have been playing around with arrays, but I can't understand whats going wrong.

This is the class:

```
public class StringArrayUtil {

        public static void print(String [] sArray){
            for(int i = 0; i<sArray.length; i++){
                if(sArray[i] !=null){
                    System.out.println("Indice: "+i+ " String: "+sArray[i] + "\t");
                }
            }
        }

        public static int indexOf(String [] sArray, String sSearch, int s){
            for(int i = s; i < sArray.length; i++){
                if(sArray[i] != null && sSearch != null && sSearch.equals(sArray[i])){
                    return i;
                }
            }   
            return -1;
        }

        public static int indexOf(String [] sArray, String sSearch){
            return indexOf(sArray, sSearch, 0);

        }

        public static int indexOfEmpty(String[] sArray){
            return indexOf (sArray,null,0);
        }

        public static int put(String[] sArray, String newS){
            for(int i = 0; i<sArray.length; i++){
                if(sArray[i] == null){
                    sArray[i]=newS;
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static int remove(String sArray, String removeS){
            int times = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++){
                if(removeS.equals(sArray[i]) ){
                    sArray[i] = null;
                    times ++;
                }
                return times;

            }
         }

        public static String fillArray (String messege, int n){
            String[] result = new String[n];
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
                result[i] = Scanner.getString (messege);
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
class StringArrayUtilTester {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("----------Welcome to StringMaster 2.0----------");
        int z=5;
        String a= "-Create a String: ";
        String [] array = StringArrayUtil.fillArray(a,z);
        String search = Scanner.getString("-String SearchBox! find and delete String: ");
        int i = StringArrayUtil.indexOf(array, search);
            if (i != -1){
                System.out.println("-The String belongs to the Array!");
                array[i] = null;
                System.out.println("...loading....");
                System.out.println("-The string has been deleted.");

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("-String not found, try another one!");
            }

        String replace = Scanner.getString("-Replace with new string: ");
        int e = StringArrayUtil.indexOfEmpty(array);
            if(e != -1){
                array[e] = replace;
            }

        System.out.println("-Final Array of Strings: ");
        StringArrayUtil.print(array);

    }
}
```

The errors I get when I try to javac i cant understand. Am I not doing my fillArray correctly? :

```
StringArrayUtilTester.java:7: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
    array =  StringArrayUtil.fillArray(a,z);
```

Comment: I copy pasted wrongly, but its still the same error: StringArrayUtilTester.java:6: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
  String [] array = StringArrayUtil.fillArray(a,z);
 LINE: 6 OF THE MAIN

Comment: Try changing the method signature of fillArrray to 
public static String[] fillArray (String messege, int n){}
Your return type, in the method signature, is a String and not a String array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type on your `fillArray` method is `String` which isn't `String[]`

You need to make the method return a `String[]` by changing the return type: `public String[] fillArray(...)`

Comment: No problem! It's worth noting that the error message described some of the problem; knowing to look there makes the errors easier to spot, which is what they're there for.

Answer (score 3):

`fillArray` returns a `String`. 
You should change the prototype to `public static String[] fillArray (String messege, int n){`

Answer (score 2):

The return type of fillArray should be String[]

```
     public static String[] fillArray (String messege, int n){
        String[] result = new String[n];
        for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
            result[i] = Scanner.getString (messege);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This still won't compile. There is no static getString() method on Scanner.

Comment: i forgot to mention i have created a class scanner a side

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in the method `fillArray`

1. The method is expecting a `String` but you return a `String[]`. Probably the method signature should be `String[]`
2. `Scanner` doesn't have a static method `getString`

You need to create an instance of `Scanner` prior to using it:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then you can do

```
result[i] = scan.next();
```

Comment: Thanks, i have a class scanner for that already it was part of my task